# Dynamically Change HTA Window Properties

Tags: dom, vbscript, hta

In my HTA, I hold it it open if an error occurred, and close it if everything was successful. At the start, I have the `sysmenu` property set to `no` because I do not want the user to close the HTA until it's finished. At the end, I want them to be able to click on the close button. Here's what I typed up to try to achieve this, but it doesn't seem to work? I suspect there is something I need to do to get the HTA to refresh it's windows properties?

**Please note that any solution that completely reloads the window and/or makes the script execute again is not acceptable**

```
If Not bHoldOpen Then
    Call window.close
Else
    Dim tagHTA
    Set tagHTA = document.getElementsByTagName("hta:application").item(0)
    Call tagHTA.setAttribute("sysmenu","yes")
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change it at runtime, its only available in the `HTA:` block as its value is used to determine how the physical window is to be initially created.

I thought you could produce a warning using the `onBeforeUnload` event & call `cancelBubble` to abort the close, but I tried it in IE8 and it still seems bugged; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946214.

It would probably be simpler and easier for the user to comprehend if you were yo just unhide a "Close" button when the process completed.

Comment: +1, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536492%28VS.85%29.aspx) states that the `sysMenu` property is read-only, which means that it can't be changed after the initial load.